# Projecting VIIRS EDR Data

Tags: coordinate-system, envi

Does anybody know of a software that can project VIIRS EDR products. I used ENVI 5.3 to project vegetation index products available on NOAA CLASS but ENVI project the images in a weird way. The two sides of the swath get projected fine but the middle of swath is missing in the projected image. Please let me know if you know any more efficient way to project these data.